# How properly retry and log rejected promise in Promise.allSettled in Node Js / typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise

I have method getPatientData which calls several search* methods which have http calls to another 3rd parity service and they return promises.

Sometimes it happens that my app doesn't return anything and a caller service failed with a timeout (I have a call timeout for 30 seconds for each service, so it is default for all services)

I suspect that one of my promise failed during execution, either because an error or also because of a timed out request, however I don't have any logs saying the reason, so probably I don't handle rejection properly and hence no logs saying the reason.

Currently I have added more logs to all search* methods, but I don't like the piece of code how organised resolve and retry.

So my question is  what is the proper way to log failed promises?
And what is the best way to combine promise retry with promise log and promise return null in case 3 retries failed?

P.S it strongly reminds me the situation in Java when you start a future, it fails in separate thread and you don't get anything if you don't handle failed future in Completablefuture.exceptionally() block.

My code snippet is below

```
async function getPatientData() {
    
    const logger: PinoLogger = new PinoLogger;
    
    const patientPromise = this.searchPatientPromise();
    const appointmentPromise = this.searchAppointmentPromise();
    const practitionerPromise = this.searchPractitionerDetailsPromise();

    let patient: any, appointment: any, practitioner: any;
    [patient, appointment, practitioner] = await resolvePromises(
        [patientPromise, appointmentPromise, practitionerPromise], retryCount, logger);
}

export const resolvePromises = async (promiseList: Promise<any>[], retryCount, logger: PinoLogger) => {
    const promiseResults = await Promise.allSettled(promiseList.map(promise => promiseRetry(promise, retryCount, logger)));
    return promiseResults.map(promiseResult => getSettledPromiseValue(promiseResult, retryCount, logger));
};

export const promiseRetry = async (promise: Promise<any>, retryCount, logger: PinoLogger): Promise<any> => {
    try {
        return await promise;
    } catch (error) {
        if (retryCount > 0) {
            logger.error('promiseRetry: Error. Promise rejected. Retrying...');
            return promiseRetry(promise, retryCount - 1, logger);
        } else {
            logger.error('promiseRetry: Error. Promise rejected. No more retries left. Returning null');
            return null;
        }
    }
};

export const getSettledPromiseValue = (promise: PromiseSettledResult<any>, encounterId: any, logger: PinoLogger): any => {
  if (promise.status === 'fulfilled') {
    return promise.value;
  } else {
    logger.error('getSettledPromiseValue: Error promise rejected ', { encounterId, message: promise.reason });
  }
  return null;
};

export const  async searchPatientPromise (): Promise<searchPatientPromise> {
    let resource;
    try {
        resource = externalService.search();
    } catch (err) {
        this.logger.error(' Error', { resourceType, queryParam: searchParams, errMessage: err.message });
        throw new Error(`Error: searchPatientPromise ${searchParams}`);
    }
    this.logger.info('searchPatientPromise successfully called');
    return resource;
}
```

I have logging in promiseRetry(), however I don't see any logs, just my application doesn't return anything.

Comment: One issue I can see,  awaiting a promise again, in your promiseRetry function, doesn't make it retry.  A promise either resolves or rejects, after that it's done it's job.

Comment: Thanks for reply, @Keith. And thanks for the spotting the issue in retry method. Is it possible however, that resolving the promise might be thrown an exception? Perhaps this is the reason why the promise is surrounded by try / catch block? Is it possible that while calling the other service, that service responded with bad request, so when the promise is being resolved it throws the exception?

Comment: What is `getSettledPromiseValue`? But yeah, the logger in `promiseRetry` should definitely log something if one of the promises failed.

Comment: It could be that one of your Promises fails, and a classic error is that you catch the error inside the promise but forget to rethrow.  For your retry logic you want to pass the function instead, you can then call the promise function  inside your retry logic.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, I have added missing pieces of code, also I have added a code for one of those 3 search methods. They are identically  e.g enclosed in try-catch block and rethrows exception in case the call is failed. So it looks like that when the promise failed (e.g call to 3rd party service failed) it must be logged, right? Or still  I need to somehow rewrite Promise.allSettled to log it properly? P.S Sorry guys for  such questions, I'm a bit new to TypeScript.

Comment: Looks like in order to log promise invocation and  failure is to append  .then() and .catch() blocks to each search* methods. like this  ``` .then(v => {console.log('search method success'); return v}).catch(e => {console.log('search method failed'); throw e;}) ```  However I would like to consolidate this logic in one place in Promise.allSettled() if possible, rather than to add this to each method.

Comment: What logs *do* you get?